# Unexpected characters in output when echo to mobile Safari

Tags: javascript, php, mobile-safari, echo

I am having a problem when attempting to echo data in a php file to mobile Safari in iOS 7.1.2.  Here is the php code:

```
        function swapFlights()
        {
            var url;
            redirect = 1;
            airline = <?php echo 'PDT'; ?>;
            url = "swap.php?date_one=" + date1 + "&flight_number_one=" + flight1 + "&dep_station_one=" + city1 + "&date_two=" + date2 + "&flight_number_two=" + flight2 + "&dep_station_two=" + city2 + "&redirect=" + redirect + "&airline=" + airline;
            window.location.href = url;
        }
```

In mobile Safari on iPhone 5S, the output is the following:

```
                function swapFlights()
                {
                    var url;
                    redirect = 1;
                    airline =
2cc1
PDT;
                    url = "swap.php?date_one=" + date1 + "&flight_number_one=" + flight1 + "&dep_station_one=" + city1 + "&date_two=" + date2 + "&flight_number_two=" + flight2 + "&dep_station_two=" + city2 + "&redirect=" + redirect + "&airline=" + airline;
                    window.location.href = url;
                }
```

The seemingly random "2cc1" is interjected, and I cannot for the life of me figure out why.  It causes a SyntaxError in the parsing of the JavaScript, rendering all of the JavaScript on the page unusable.  In every other browser I've tried (desktop Safari, Firefox), the code is output correctly as one would expect:

```
        function swapFlights()
        {
            var url;
            redirect = 1;
            airline = PDT;
            url = "swap.php?date_one=" + date1 + "&flight_number_one=" + flight1 + "&dep_station_one=" + city1 + "&date_two=" + date2 + "&flight_number_two=" + flight2 + "&dep_station_two=" + city2 + "&redirect=" + redirect + "&airline=" + airline;
            window.location.href = url;
        }
```

Any ideas, or is this more likely a bug in mobile Safari itself?  I've searched all over the internet, but can't seem to find any other instances of this problem.

Changing the php to:

```
             redirect = 1;
             <?php echo 'airline = PDT'; ?>;
```

results in the unknown characters being slightly different, and appearing earlier in the output:

```
                    redirect = 1;

2ccb
airline = PDT;
```

I should have specified that my goal is the replace the 'PDT' with the string variable $airline.  I changed the variable to the literal 'PDT' thinking I may have had a problem with the datatype of the variable, but that wasn't the case.

Comment: What happens if you change the PHP to `airline = PDT;`?

Comment: I edited the original post to include what you suggested.  The unexpected characters now appear before the 'airline', and have changed slightly.  (2ccb instead of 2cc1)

Comment: So you're getting some junk wherever you have `<?php echo`, it appears. Very weird.

Comment: Yes, I agree.  Even weirder is that it isn't wherever I use it.  About 15 lines after this example, I use it 5 more times without any problems.  Another couple hundred lines after that, another mysterious 4 characters appear at the <?php echo again, only this time they are '2d3a'.

Comment: It looks like a hex code, maybe a line or character number.

Comment: 2ccb = 11467, 2d3a = 11578

Comment: You probably have a PDT variable. Try `airline = '<?php echo 'PDT'; ?>';`.

Comment: I believe this is a bug in iOS 7.1.2.  The same website on my iPad mini (still running iOS 7.0.4) has no issues with the website.  I may try to rollback the iPhone iOS to see if the issue goes away.  Also, I'm going to try to update the iPad to 7.1.2 and see if the issue appears there as well.  Thanks for your help.